# Should thick (softwood) joint be drawbored through and through?

Tags: mortise-and-tenon, drawbore

**What are some valid considerations to help decide whether drawbore holes should be blind? (or go through the back)**

I'm building a roubo-style bench with thick douglas fir legs (4"x6") and stretchers (2"x6"). The stretchers are joined to the leg with mortise and tenon. In the instructions, the tenons are preferably drawbored tight against the legs.

However, it is not specified whether the drawbore peg should go through the stretcher and leg completely (i.e. so the peg pokes out at the back of the leg), or whether to make the drawbore hole stop shy of the backside of the leg.

I have limited drawboring experience, but I have some concerns (which may or may not be considered valid by an experienced woodworker):

- Longer pegs break more easily.
- In other projects with softwood, I've also had chip breakage on the exit side around the peg hole.
- I was planning on using 3/8" dry dowel and a 23/64" hole (i.e. hole is 1/64" smaller), and make the holes 1" away from the edge of the joint. Maybe dowel diameter doesn't change much of anything, others seem to settle on approx 1/2" peg for that bench.

[image: drawbore location]

Comment: Is part of the reason for the drawbore to have the ability to disassemble? If so, a through hole is way easier.

Comment: Good luck getting a 3/8” dowel into a 15/64” hole!

Comment: @Caleb ah! i meant 23/64th, i.e. 1/64th smaller. will edit. excuse the arithmetic. the one time i did that, i “shrunk” the dowels beforehand in the oven (or microwave) to shrink them before hammering them in. the hole, being a smidge smaller compensates for some of the irregularities in the drill hole and on the circumference of the dowel (esp if you’ve punched it through a dowel plate).

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I wasn’t planning on ever disassembling the base, but i believe you may be on to something with that comment. Is ease of disassembly the only thing worth considering? I’ve never taken a drawbore apart… is that simply done by knocking the old dowel halfway out with a pin? (assuming it’s not glued in place)

Comment: Hey, long time no see. Congrats on what may be your forever-workbench build! There are a few key drawbore points hidden in the body text and in the Comments,  I think they're mostly covered in the links provided by @VolframK but do ask a separate Question to cover them if you'd like.

Comment: I built a roubo workbench years ago with a 4" thick top.  The legs have a shouldered top that fits with recesses on the underside of the slab.  The fit is snug.  I did not pin the connection at all and have never had a problem with movement on the bench. Plus, removing the top will be simple if I ever have to relocate it.

Comment: @Ashlar Good work!  The fit of the legs is snug against my benchtop too, but each leg turned out to have a different personality. Each is ever-so-slightly (prob  1-2degree) out of square with the top. A mistake I made is cutting my stretchers _before_ fitting the legs in their final slots. So, I'm planning on assembling the base, sliding in all 4 legs and stretchers at once (without drawbore pegs), and hammering the drawbores in stretchers as the final step. I'm hoping that the drawbores will tilt the legs back closer to square and yield tighter shoulders with stretchers.

Comment: Non-square legs aren't any sort of issue. I'm sure there's many a bench where one or more legs isn't entirely plumb due to miss-measurement or a snafu during installation, and of course there are benches where the legs are deliberately at an angle. As long as the feet are level and everything is tight you'll never know as far as performance goes. If you can notice the tilts and the aesthetics bother you then you'll need to cut new stretchers, or stretch/shrink the ones you have (edit: that's not a joke BTW, you can do this by scarfing).

Comment: Ask your concerns in a separate Q, they'll probably go un-answered here unless it's in the Comments and will be harder or impossible for future searchers to find because they won't realise they fall under this title, or the search can't locate them.

Answer (score 6):

It does not matter. Through hole or stopped hole, hold of pin is the same.

[Drawboring Resurrected](https://www.popularwoodworking.com/techniques/drawboring-resurrected/)
[Drawboring
Demystified](https://popularwoodworking.com/wp-content/uploads/Drawboring.pdf)

Reason not to bore through is if you do not want to see pins on both sides of leg, does not seem important on workbench. **In theory** drawbore pins through leg can be knocked out later if needed, but best of luck if you try!

> In other projects with softwood, I've also had chip breakage on the exit side around the peg hole.

Does not matter. Workbench, not furniture!

Reminder: drawboring is option, not requirement. **Many** workbenches do not have drawbores, all joints still tight after 70+ years. How old are you? :)

Good reason to use them today is if clamps long enough are not available.